# QGIS Triangle marker size control

Tags: qgis, markers, qgis-expression

I have a series of points along a line and I want to project a 'beam' of acoustic energy from each one. I am looking to see how the beam might overlap. The beam is 0.5 degrees (+/- 0.25 degrees) and extends out to a function of the water depth.
Using the Triangle Simple Marker in Symbology, I can control the heading of the beam and the length (height of the triangle) by applying equations in the Data Defined Override for both Size and Rotation.  Unfortunately, the calculated height of the triangle is also applied to the base width of the triangle. There does not seem to be a way to independently control the two dimensions. Is there a way to define either the angle (0.5 degrees) or apply a base width for the triangle? I am using a normal triangle and not the Equilateral. The base width will also vary with the length/water depth.

The calculation for length of beam is `"Depth" * sin(radians(45))`
If my basic Trig is correct, the equation for the base width would be `"Depth" * tan(radians(0.25)) * 2`

The input data is as below, the axes of the triangle/beam heading is 90 degrees to the HDG.

| X | Y | Depth | HDG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 641650.10 | 7988087.10 | 279 | 86.44511133 |
| 641653.09 | 7988087.29 | 266 | 86.44511133 |
| 641656.09 | 7988087.47 | 243 | 86.44511133 |

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the SVG triangle.
[image: SVG Symbology]

Select the equilateral SVG triangle, unlock the lock in the right of Width and Height settings, then set the expression in Width and Height.
This are my expressions:

**Width:** `"Depth" * 2 * tan(radians("HDG" / 2))`

**Height:** `"Depth"`